# Query in MySQL for string fields with a specific length

Tags: mysql, sql, string

How can I make a MySQL query asking for all the string fields in a column that have a particular length?

Thanks!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) for checking length in bytes:

```
SELECT str FROM sometable WHERE LENGTH(str) = 5;
```

Or [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) for checking length in number of characters (useful for multi-byte strings):

```
SELECT str FROM sometable WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(str) = 5;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select * 
from myTable 
where length(myColumn) = 5
```